# GDAL not accepting *.tif to list through files in directory

Tags: gdal

I am using gdal_merge.py to mosaic tif. If I explicitly write the file names it works, but if I use *.tif it fails with the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal_merge.py", line 509, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal_merge.py", line 392, in main
    ulx = file_infos[0].ulx
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: As to why it is working if you look at the script itself it does not import glob, the module python needs to do file expansion.  It is literally looking for a tif file named *, not all files that end in .tif.

Comment: Globbing is usually done by the shell but OP did not mention their actual gdal_merge.py invocation so ...

Answer (score 8):

What I would recommend, although you could also file through this with some sort of batch loop:

```
dir /b *.tif > list_of_tiff_files.txt
gdalbuildvrt -input_file_list list_of_tiff_files.txt vrt_of_files.vrt
gdal_merge vrt_of_files.vrt -o merged.tif
```

So `gdalbuildvrt` works with a list of files, and `gdal_merge` should work with a virtual raster file (vrt).

Comment: Thank you, Vesanto, but it's necessary to include the -input_file_list parameter before namelist. http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html

Comment: gdal_merge takes '-o' for output.

Comment: I have added that, hope that helps.